# Are meta-analyses only secondary analyses which require uses of the post-hoc statistical methods?

Tags: meta-analysis, post-hoc, clinical-trials

Randomized clinical trials (RCT) require pre-registration with protocols, and the primary outcome is the only credible outcome, whereas secondary outcomes and sub-group analyses are only exploratory and requires further RCTs to confirm. Do meta-analyses also have the same requirements as the individual RCT? Are they only secondary analyses which require uses of the post-hoc statistical methods?

Answer (score 2):

On the contrary systematic reviews can and should have their protocol registered. An example is the Prospero data base https://www.crd.york.ac.uk/PROSPERO/ which is probably the first example although I believe there are others. Journals have not yet taken to requiring pre-registration in the same way as for trials but presumably that will come. The protocol would include details of the outcome to be used and the analytical methods required in the same way as for a trial.